# Number of value occurences grouped by GroupID in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset which has multiple columns and multiple values for each column. What I want is to have the count of each value from each column grouped by a groupID

**Example**

```
 GroupId | C1            |    C2
      1  | "valColOne1"  | "valColTwo2"
      2  |  "valColOne1" | "valColTwo2"
      2  |  "valColOne1" | "valColTwo2"
      2  |  "valColOne2" | "valColTwo1"
      1  |  "valColOne1" | "valColTwo1"
```

**And the result should be**

```
    GroupId | valColOne1 | valColOne2 | valColTwo1 | valColTwo2
         1  |    2       |     0      |    1       |  1
         2  |    2       |     1      |    1       |  2
```

To mention that all values in the intial table will be strings.

Comment: using `dplyr/tidyr`,  group_by, do(table), spread might do.

Comment: @Khashaa thanks. Can you expand a little on that. Im not a real expert on R so any further explanation would be helpful.

Comment: You already have a couple of nice answers:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your original data frame (which I've called `dat`) and `melt` it into long format. Then use `dcast` to count the number of occurrences of each value.

```
library(reshape2)

dat.m = melt(dat, id.var="GroupId")

dcast(dat.m, GroupId ~ value)

  GroupId   valColOne1    valColOne2   valColTwo1  valColTwo2
1       1             2             0           1           1
2       2             2             1           1           2
```

It's easiest to see what each function does if you run them and look at the intermediate results. For some examples, see [here](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) and [here](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/reshape-and-aggregate-data-with-the-r-package-reshape2/).

Comment: Great! Can you explain what each function does ? never used reshape before.

Comment: Also really nice package. wouldn't thought there would be such a easy way to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `table` from `base R`

```
table(data.frame(GroupId= df1$GroupId, Val=unlist(df1[-1])))
#         Val
# GroupId valColOne1 valColOne2 valColTwo1 valColTwo2
#  1          2          0          1          1
#  2          2          1          1          2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GroupId = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1), C1 = c("valColOne1", 
"valColOne1", "valColOne1", "valColOne2", "valColOne1"), 
C2 =   c("valColTwo2", 
"valColTwo2", "valColTwo2", "valColTwo1", "valColTwo1")),
.Names =  c("GroupId", 
"C1", "C2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```